# Scripting find and replace (for tick boxes)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've seen multiple responses to various find and replace scripting questions and tried to implementing any number of them and they just dont work, and I can't just macro record it either, so sorry to ask a repeated question but;

I'm working on a workbook where supervisors will verify the data inputted by ticking a tick box, then when everyone is done admin user will save the sheet out, and then run a reset script that will untick all the tick boxes.

As above, i've tried numerous variations on find and replace solutions to replace all the 'True' values with 'False' which works just fine from the actual 'find and replace' function, but I can't get it to script, and would much rather that solution.

I've also tried macro recording selecting the column that has all the tick boxes and toggling with spacebar input twice, but this is also not recorded.

I don't really have any pre-existing code to share, since everything I've tried is solutions I have already read here that seem to work for others but modifying the variables in my sheet doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

It is very straightforward.

You can use [clear()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clear) on a particular `range` to untick the checkboxes or in other words, make them `FALSE`.

**Code snippet:**

Choose the name of the sheet `sheetName`  and the range `rng` of the checkboxes you want to untick.

```
function untickBoxes() {
    const rng = 'A1:A5'; // choose the range of the tick boxes you want to untick
    const sheetName = 'Sheet1'; // choose the name of your sheet        
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    sheet.getRange(rng).clear(); // untick all the tick boxes of rng
}
```